# Download .PDF at the next page after successful form insertion in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I have a form, that user has to fill out. After pressing submit, the user will be redirected to page called /medicines/result with a success message and download button for the .PDF. I cannot figure out how to download the pdf on the download page. If I use the pdf method in the controller, it works fine.

I am using this for pdf: [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

What I have:

```
public function store(StoreConfirmationRequest $request) {
    $formData = $request->all();

    $prescription_confirmation = new Prescription_confirmations;
    $prescription_confirmation->physician_id = Input::get('physician_id');
    $prescription_confirmation->patient_code = Input::get('patient_code');
    $prescription_confirmation->medicine = 1;
    $prescription_confirmation->date = Input::get('physician_date');

    //finally save the data to database
    $prescription_confirmation->save();

    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
    $pdf->download();

    return view('medicines.result', compact('formData'))->with('message', 'Successfully inserted);
}
```

Here is the blade

```
 @extends ('layouts/master')

    @section('title', 'Allalaadimine')

        @section ('content')
        <div class="container medicine_confirmation_container">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            @foreach ($formData as $data)
              <li>{{$data}}</li>
            @endforeach
            <div class="flash-message">
              @if(session()->has('message'))
                  <div class="alert-message alert-message-success">
                    <h4>Saved!</h4>
                      {{ session()->get('message') }}
                  </div>
              @endif
            </div> <!-- end .flash-message -->
            <button class="btn btn-borders btn-success btn-lg btnDownloadPdf" type="submit">Lae alla pdf</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        @endsection

        @section ('footer')
        @endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning both the PDF and a view won't work. You have to save the PDF on your server and make it accessible to download by another route.

From: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

```
$pdf->save('/path-to/my_stored_file.pdf');
```

In the blade template you have to link your saved PDF.

Comment: that would be really heavy on the server?

Comment: You can also generate the PDF on request, via a separate route. In this case you don't have to store the file.